# Exporting monthly NDWI images

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, normalized-difference-water-index

I am trying to export monthly NDWI images for about 15 years from LANDSAT5 images. This is my code. for exporting 180 monthly NDWI images, I have some problems and the code does not work well. How can I improve the code?

```js
//////////////////////////geometry
var geometry =  table;
Map.centerObject(geometry);
//print (geometry);
Map.addLayer(geometry);
//////////////////////////images
var L5 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_TOA')
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .filterDate('1984-04-01', '1999-12-30')
//print (L5);

/////////////////////////////////////METHOD 1
var cloudlessNDWI = L5.map(function(image) {
  // Get a cloud score in [0, 100].
  var cloud = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleCloudScore(image).select('cloud');

  // Create a mask of cloudy pixels from an arbitrary threshold.
  var mask = cloud.lte(20);

  // Compute NDWI.
  var ndwi = image.normalizedDifference(['B2', 'B4']).rename('NDWI');

  // Return the masked image with an NDWI band.
  return image.addBands(ndwi).updateMask(mask);
});

// print (cloudlessNDWI); 
  
  var months = ee.List.sequence(1, 180);
print(months)
   
 var MMonthlyMeans = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  months.map(function (m) {
    var filteredCollection = cloudlessNDWI
      .filterBounds(geometry)
      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
      .sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', false);
    var meanImage = filteredCollection.mean().set('month', m);
    return meanImage.clip(geometry);
  })
);
print (MMonthlyMeans); 
// Define the export parameters.
var exportParams = {
  region: geometry,
  scale: 30,
  crs: 'EPSG:4326',
  maxPixels: 1e13
};

// Loop through the collection and export each image.
var count = MMonthlyMeans.size().getInfo();
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  // Get the image at the current index.
  var image = ee.Image(MMonthlyMeans.toList(count).get(i));

  // Get the month of the image.
  var month = ee.Number(image.get('month'));

  // Set the export name.
  var exportName = 'NDWI_' + month.format('%02d');

  // Export the image to Google Drive.
  Export.image.toDrive({
    image: image.select('NDWI'),
    description: exportName,
    folder: 'NDWI_Images',
    fileNamePrefix: exportName,
    region: geometry,
    scale: 30,
    crs: 'EPSG:4326',
    maxPixels: 1e13
  });
}
```

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to describe the "problems" you are encountering. We are a *problem-solving* site, not [codereview.se].

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I see in your code is the variable `ExportName`. You are assuming `month` to be a number, but it is an object instead. Therefore, the variable `ExportName` has a JSON-like structure, which is too long for the exported image. You can solve it by using `getInfo()`.

```
// Set the export name.

  var exportName = 'NDWI_' + month.getInfo()
```